# Lambda (node) Express REST API with AWS API Gateway 502 Bad Gateway error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a react front app which invokes rest api based on lambda and express. The integration is done via AWS API Gateway. Even the with the cors module I do not achieve what I want.

This is the code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

require('dotenv').config();
const youTube = require('./lib/youtube');
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const Logger = require('./lib/logger');
const cors = require('cors');
const serverLogger = new Logger(__filename);

// Init Middleware
app.use(express.json({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ msg: 'Welcome to the YouTube downloader API...' });
});


app.post('/api/youtube/download', async (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body;
    const { url } = body;

    res.header('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=video.mp3');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS,POST,GET');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    
    const youTubeStream = await youTube.getStream(url);
    ffmpeg(youTubeStream)
        .format('mp3')
        .audioBitrate('192k')
        .on('end', function () {
            console.log('file has been converted succesfully');
            res.status(200);
        })
        .on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('an error happened: ' + err.message);
            res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
        })
        // save to stream
        .pipe(res, { end: true });
});
app.post('/api/youtube/info', async (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body;
    console.log(body);
    const { url } = body;

    const title = await youTube.getInfo(url);
    console.log(title);
    res.status(200).json({ title: title });
});

module.exports = app;
```

I keep on getting this message:

Access to fetch at '...' from origin '...' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: In the first stanza, you're setting `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` and `res.status(200);`.  Good!  Q: Are you getting the CORS error here, despite your (apparently correct) response headers?  Q: Have you looked at the network requests/responses in Chrome Developer Tools > Network (or equivalent)?

Comment: I looked into the developer tools and I can see this:

content-length: 36
content-type: application/json
date: Wed, 30 Sep 2020 22:09:29 GMT
status: 502
x-amz-apigw-id: Ts1DmEUgFiAFkLg=
x-amzn-errortype: InternalServerErrorException
x-amzn-requestid: 4458cf7a-a908-4a3f-bdf4-167f06055c6b

Comment: The problem is that 502 error, not CORS

Comment: Sideshowbarker is correct: the HTTP 502 is the real problem.  Unfortunately, his response in the so-called "duplicate" doesn't really give you any useful troubleshooting advice.  Look here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/handling-errors/.  It's not much, but I hope it helps.

Comment: @John Rotenstein - any suggestions to help resolve the problem?  Q: Would you consider adding your vote to "reopen"?